# Symfony2 Forms: validate related entity property

Tags: symfony

I have entity `Message` with ManyToOne relation with entity `User`:

```
class Message
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var User $sender
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sender_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     **/
    private $sender;
    ...
    }
```

If `$sender` doesn't have `email` value i need to create new field for my form, so i create form for `Message` entity in Contoller:

```
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $message = new Message();
    $message->setSender($user);

    $formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($message, array(
        'cascade_validation' => true
    ));

    $formBuilder->add('body', 'textarea');

    if (!$user->getEmail()) {
        $formBuilder->add('email', 'email', array(
            'property_path' => 'sender.email'
        ));
    }
```

And i have some validation rules in `validation.yml` for entity `User`. Can i automatically validate this field by my validation rules for `User` entity in another entity's form? I don't know how to do it.

I found workaround right now: create new `MissingEmailType`:

```
class MissingEmailType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array(
                'MissingEmail'
            ),
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'missing_email';
    }
}
```

But it looks complicated. Is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the page to the user profile page instead of loading the message form and state that the user needs to add an email prior to adding the message.  If you redirect quickly or create a popup, the user might not be turned off as long as they can return to the original page after adding their email.  Then validtion is simple since you only need to validate the user entity.